# Facebook scrape returns 502 error

Tags: facebook, screen-scraping

I'm just trying to use standard link sharing using Facebook's sharer.php url.  Here is a sample link:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fbsfurl.com%2FhTM9%2F2%2F2&t=Welcome!

I've been doing this successfully since 2009. Recently the Facebook sharer page seems to no longer be able to access my link to pull in images and a description.  Using the Facebook Object debugger,

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/

I see that every URL that i try returns a HTTP 502 error.  Can someone help me understand why this is happening?  Even a static HTML page returns this same error.  Here is a screenshot of the error: http://images.publicaster.com/ImageLibrary/account116/images/facebookscrapeerror.png

Testing the URL in a browser works fine: http://stagingclick.publicaster.com/test.htm.  this is just a static link no dynamic content, no redirects nothing.  I'm a little at a loss of what i can do to fix this error.  In my IIS logs i am not able to see the incoming request from Facebook's scraper.

Thanks!
-mark

Answer (score 0):

The page you linked `(http://stagingclick.publicaster.com/test.htm`) is redirected (via the `og:url` tag) to http://www.nin.ja which doesn't resolve - are you sure there isn't a similar problem with the live links you're sharing?